# I can't get IIS7 to show my MVC 3 page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, http-status-code-403

I had to re-format my PC and now I can't seem to get my MVC 3 web application to show up.

I get the error:

```
The website declined to show this webpage

Most likely causes:
   •This website requires you to log in.
```

I tried creating a new MVC 3 project from scratch and it gets the same error.

I created an ASP.Net web site and it seems to work fine.

I have anonymous turned on in IIS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure exactly what the problem was, but I uninstalled and re-installed IIS, then re-ran aspnet_regiis -ir and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. I solved it by changing the .Net Framework in the online console that my ISP provided to ".Net 4 including integrated pipeline". I also included the MVC DLLs in the bin.

I hope this helps....